# Clear localStorage when killing IE process from Task Manager

Tags: javascript, html

I am using HTML5 localStorage to track my application session. Below is the my code sample.

```
             if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
             {
                if(sessionStorage.lastname=="Smith")
                {
                    alert( "your Session is still active");

                }
                else{
                sessionStorage.lastname="Smith";
                   alert( "Last name: " + sessionStorage.lastname);
                }
                }
              else
                {
                alert( "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...");
                }
```

The above code works great. But when I close my IE browser from Task Manage > kill IE process, and open my application again in a new browser, then I see my old localStorage value still exist, it does not delete my localStorage of previous session.

How can I delete the localStorage, when user kills the browser from TaskManager?

Comment: SessionStorage will be persists until the browser is open . If you open a browser there is no session storage will be exists . No chance for old value exists .

Comment: I am using the IE8 and can not go with sessionStorage because in IE8> if you do the new session it creates the new browser session and you can not share the Storage data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the browser is killed via the task manager, the javascript process is subsequently killed.  When javascript is killed it does not fire an event that you can act on.

http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/javascript-dhtml-ajax/threads/232931/is-it-possible-detect-browser-process-termination#

Comment: Thanks Scott, is there any alternative which i can use which helps to achieve my requirement.

Comment: You may want to look at your business logic.  Is there any other time you're going to clear your local cache?  For example, if it when the page loads initially you want the local storage cleared?  I don't know your application so I can't think through the logic too much, but maybe you could have some sort of expiration time for your values in local storage, and extend it at regular intervals.  If the page is killed then it won't be extended, and on page load you can check that expiration variable, if it is invalid, clear the local storage.